# If $G$ has a normal series then a subgroup $H$ of $G$ also have one

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism

> **Definition:** A sequence $(G_0,G_1,\cdots,G_r)$ of subgroups of a group $G$ is called a normal series (or subnormal series) of $G$ if $$\{e\}=G_0\lhd G_1\lhd\cdots\lhd G_r=G$$
> The factors of a normal series are the quotient groups $G_i/G_{i-1},1\leq i\leq r$.

If $G$ has a normal series $\{e\}=G_0\lhd G_1\lhd\cdots\lhd G_r=G$ then any subgroup $H$ also have one by using there exists a natural homomorphism, $$H_{i+1}\rightarrow G_{i+1}/G_i$$
Where $H_i:=G_i\cap H$ and further use $$H_{i+1}/H_i\cong G_{i+1}/G_i$$

I understand their role in order to prove this kind of theorems but can't think or visual that isomorphism (explicitly) by my own.

Any suggestions, comments, resources or solution will be appreciated.

---

updated: [In section 3, Normal series under group constructions](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/subgpseries1.pdf), there was similar argument for a subgroup, quotient group, and direct product.

**Here, $G_i$ is normal in $G_{i+1}$**

I don't see how to ensure an isomorphism from $H_{i+1}/H_i$ to **A SUBGROUP** of $G_{i+1}/G_i$. Like element of $H_{i+1}/H_i$  is $hH_i$ where $h\in H\cap G_{i+1}$, and element of $G_{i+1}/G_i$ is $gG_i$ where $g\in G_{i+1}$.

Comment: You need to say what you mean by a normal series. There are two different definitions in widespread use. Do you mean all $G_i$ are normal in $G$ or just normal in $G_{i+1}$? I prefer to call the second type a subnormal series.

Comment: You say that "use $H_{i+1}/H_i\cong G_{i+1}/G_i$ " but that's not true in general. (After all, if true it will make $|G|=|H|$.)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, @DerekHolt I add the definition.

Comment: The textbook use that in their prove. @ancientmathematician

Comment: "prove" is the verb. "proof" is the noun. "In their prove" is incorrect. So is "I proof that".

Comment: Your added definition did not clarify which condition you meant.

Comment: I don't know why I am missing that, thanks @ArturoMagidin I got similar argument [In section 3, Normal series under group constructions](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/subgpseries1.pdf).

Comment: You are not saying if you require $G_i$ normal in $G$ for all $i$, or only require $G_i$ normal in $G_{i+1}$. The former implies the latter, but not viceversa.

Comment: The paper in your update gives the correct statement that $H_{i+1}/H_i$ is isomorphic to A SUBGROUP of $G_{i+1}/G_i$.

Comment: But still, I don't see how to ensure an isomorphism from $H_{i+1}/H_i$ to **A SUBGROUP** of $G_{i+1}/G_i$. Like element of $H_{i+1}/H_i$  is $hH_i$ where $h\in H\cap G_{i+1}$, and element of $G_{i+1}/G_i$ is $gG_i$ where $h\in G_{i+1}$. @ancientmathematician

Comment: This is exactly Thm 3.1 of your PDF and the proof is given there: it's a straightforward application of the Homomorphism Thm: we have a map - the natural map - from $H_{i+1}$ to $G_{i+1}/G_i$ whose kernel is clearly $H_i$.

Comment: Okay, I understand. But seriously I couldn't feel that natural map, $H_{i+1}\rightarrow G_{i+1}/G_i$. It might be my lack of knowledge. Can you enlighten me by explicitly mentioning that?